# Removing Extra Spaces in numbers in a text

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Is any way to remove extra spaces from numbers in a sentence without using a heavy regex?

I did this code, but it seem take a lot of time when I execute it for a huge input text.

```
    String text = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(?<![.,/])[0-9]+) +(?=[0-9]+[$|€|£|¥|￥|%|°])", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(?<![.,/])[0-9]+), +(?=[0-9]+[$|€|£|¥|￥|%|°])", ",");
    text = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(?<![.,/])[0-9]+)\\. +(?=[0-9]+[$|€|£|¥|￥|%|°])", ".");
    text = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(?<![.,/\\-//%€£¥￥°\\$])[0-9]+) +(?=[0-9]+\\s?\\b(?![.,/\\-//%€£¥￥°\\$]))", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(?<![.,/\\-//%€£¥￥°\\$])[0-9]+), +(?=[0-9]+\\s?\\b(?![.,/\\-//%€£¥￥°\\$]))", ",");
    text = text.replaceAll("(?<=\\b(?<![.,/\\-//%€£¥￥°\\$])[0-9]+)\\. +(?=[0-9]+\\s?\\b(?![.,/\\-//%€£¥￥°\\$]))", ".");
```

For ex. for **input**:

```
bla bla bla 12, 09 bata tata 11. 02
```

**output** should be

```
bla bla bla 12,09 bata tata 11.02
```

Notice how spaces in between the decimal numbers are removed.

Comment: can you give an example input and expected ouput

Comment: Right @pvpkiran please give The Example Of YouR Output

Comment: Example for text = "bla bla bla 12.         09 bata tata 11. 0" I get "bla bla bla 12.09 bata tata 11.0"

Comment: What do you mean by "extra spaces" in numbers in a text? is it consecutive extra spaces within a string? or is it consecutive extra spaces before / after number characters within a string? For the time being, this website: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html is really useful for testing regex in java.

Comment: @Dr.Mza So you want to remove spaces between a decimal point and preceding and following digits?

Comment: in a text each time we have a number such (XX. DD) we remove the space 11.  34 will be 11.34 .. 11,                34 will be 11,34

Comment: @shreyasminocha Yes indeed

Comment: @Dr.Mza are you trying to remove all whitespaces preceding all numbers (regardless whether there is a period, comma or any other character)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do like this:**

```
String str = "bla bla bla 12. 09 bata tata 11. 02";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\\d+[\\.,])\\s+(\\d+)", "$1$2"));
```

**Outputs:**

```
bla bla bla 12.09 bata tata 11.02
```

**About regex used:**

Its any number of digits followed by a `.` or `,`, followed by any whitespaces, followed by any number. 
We have used grouping in the regex.

Comment: +1 thank you boss, I have juste one execption, If I have for example 11 000 without . and , how to manage it ?

Comment: Use this regex in that case `(\d+[\.,\s]*)\s+(\d+)`. I'd advise you to play around with regex online. You can start with https://regex101.com/.

Comment: The period does not need to be escaped with a backslash when it is inside brackets.  Meaning, `[.,]` is sufficient.